# Cannot query Firestore due to security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

These are my rules. User can only access accounts associated with that user (account document has field `users` containing uid)

```js
function isLoggedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
}

function getAccount(accountID) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(accountID)).data;
}

function isBelongTo(accountID) {
    return isLoggedIn() && (request.auth.uid in getAccount(accountID).users);
}

match /accounts/{accountID}/{documents=**} {
    allow read: if isBelongTo(accountID);
}
```

This works fine on the rules playground. But when I do a query in firebase javascript sdk in a browser like this

```js
onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "accounts"), where('users', 'array-contains', uid ? uid : '')), (querySnapshot) => {
  const docs = [];
  // querySnapshot does not have .map, so we have to use .forEach
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>

    docs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
  );
  console.log(docs);
});
```

it returns an empty array (in my larger project but not the demo linked below) and returns a permission error.

if i first get a single document with the below code, then the query above returns the document /accounts/35 in the query snapshot, and also returns a permission error:

```js
  onSnapshot(doc(db, "accounts", "35"), (doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      // console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
      // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
  })
```

I'm made a [sample repo](https://github.com/nknguyen19/firebase-demo) and here is the result:
[image: console results of attached repo]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you are saying you used the Firebase Admin SDK for nodejs to make the query, you should not see any permission problems at all.  Backend SDKs initialized by a service account always bypass all rules entirely.  Rules only apply to web and mobile SDKs.

Comment: There's also not enough information here for us to see everything that's happening.  The rules are incomplete (we can't see `isLoggedIn()`) and we can't see the value of `uid`, nor do we know for certain if there is a user signed in at the time of the query.

Comment: In addition to Doug's comment about `isLoggedIn()` missing, you should also remove `uid ? uid : ''` as performing a query with a missing `uid` value will result in the query failing anyway (which could be caused by a typo, the user not being logged in or your state not properly updating).

Comment: @DougStevenson i'm working with nguyen and have updated the question to address your comments

Comment: @Jayen , based on your edit, are you not seeing the permission error that nguyen originally posted? could you provide a reproducible code that we can see where the variable `uid` came from and how it is being passed into your `onSnapshot()` (please include the value of your `uid`. console log it if possible). And to add, `doc()` and `query()` are different methods which makes your question more confusing.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB there is a permissions error, but i believe that is unrelated and comes based on the way we use the empty array returned, so that is why i have removed it in my edit.  i'll see if we can make a small git repo that reproduces the issue more clearly.  uid is coming from firebase-auth as the current user, who is logged in with email.  doc and query are different methods so we are confused why doc makes the query work.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB we're getting BOTH an array and a permission error, so we are very confused as the snapshot listener works and doesn't work at the same time.  i've attached an example repo and a screenshot of the console